# After upgrading to angular 12, app is throwing run time error "Uncaught TypeError: i is not a function"

Tags: webpack-5, angular12

Recently I upgraded angular app to 12 version, ng serve and ng build works fine.

```
Pakage json for custom webpack
 "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^12.0.0-beta.0",
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.0"
}
```

After moving code to prod getting run time error like below and it's difficult to find out the root cause

```
Uncaught TypeError: i is not a function
    at Object.12966 (main-es2015.18bf0e6d3748c0de495c.js:1)
    at a (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.6273 (main-es2015.18bf0e6d3748c0de495c.js:1)
    at a (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.41802 (main-es2015.18bf0e6d3748c0de495c.js:1)
    at a (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.12256 (main-es2015.18bf0e6d3748c0de495c.js:1)
    at a (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.62097 (main-es2015.18bf0e6d3748c0de495c.js:1)
    at a (bootstrap:19)
```